# Bot connects to voice channel, but I get errors saying it's not connected?

Tags: discord.py

I've been having this weird issue where the bot connects to the voice channel, but then I get errors saying it's not connected? I found this on github which I've used as a base https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py and it was working just fine yesterday, but today it just broke. I get an exception thrown with `channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel` saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel' although changing it to just `channel = ctx.author.voice.channel` seems to fix it though? I also get an issue with `ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)` saying Not connected to voice. even though it is.

```
#Join Command
   @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if not channel:
            await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
            return
        voice = discord.utils.get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
        await voice.disconnect()
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel}")
```

```
#Player Command
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,*,url):
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.client.loop)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

        await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(player.title))
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("") #testing reactions
```

Comment: So, what I can say that it's as you guessed not `ctx.message.author.voice.channel` but ctx.author.voice.channel. I don't know much about ffmpeg as I am also still trying (in background) to create a music bot

Comment: Oh is there something else other than ffmpeg? That's just the way I've learned so far and seems to be the most common form tutorials I've seen. Also I just wanna mention that the code I had was working just fine yesterday so no idea what happened today lol.